# Configuring SSL for Ruby on rails application (in ubuntu) + AWS using LBS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, ssl, https, elastic-load-balancer

I am new to ruby on rails, Right now have developed an application and deploying it to AWS server. I have installed ruby on rails in Ubuntu OS using the doc in digital ocean website. After deployed, everything is working fine.

Now, I need to configure SSL (HTTPS) for entire application. I have hosted the files in AWS EC2, and have used AWS Loadbalancer and ACM

I don't know what is the default web server ROR is using and how to enable SSL in ROR environment. I am getting timeout whenever I access the application in HTTPS mode.

I have checked clearly, as I have added HTTPS (443) protocol in my instance as well as in Loadbalancer listener.

Any advice / clear explanation on what is going on there and What I missed would help me in getting it right.

Thanks,

Comment: try checking this once: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-an-instance.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable a production ready web service with RoR, you also need an HTTP server and app server. For HTTP server, most popular ones are Nginx and Apache. For app server, you can use Phusion Passenger or Puma. I used Nginx with Phusion Passenger. If this is your choice, you need to buy an SSL certificate from any vendor and put it on the ec2 instance. Set up the ssl certificate in Nginx using 443 port.

On LBS side, you need to connect the LBS 443 to your ec2 433 port so that the request can be forwarded.

-------Edit----------

The above answer is not the easiest way for LBS. AWS Application Load Balancer can directly hand application layer protocol like HTTPS. So there is no need to setup it on EC2 if you don't want to directly talk to your EC2 server. EC2 server can always use HTTP if you trust your private network.